# Managing Observable Subscriptions with Synchronous Streams

Tags: rxjs

#### The Problem

If an observable is running synchronously, then the callback that is given to `subscribe` is executed **before** `subscribe` returns. The result is that the following code gives an error. (sub is not initialized)

```
const sub = from([1,2,3,4,5]).subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) sub.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});
```

#### A Nieve Solution

If we force the values of our stream into the event loop, we no longer have this problem. `Subscribe` will always return before the lambda is called.

```
const sub = from([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  delay(0)
).subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) sub.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});
```

This, however, strikes me as a bad idea. If for no other reason than performance. Though it also makes the run-order less deterministic (Which Browser?, NodeJS?).

#### The Idiomatic RxJS Solution

Don't unsubscribe yourself, let an operator do that for you

```
const unsub = new Subject();
from([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  takeUntil(unsub)
).subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) {
    unsub.next();
    unsub.complete();
  }
  console.log(x);
});
```

The problem here is that we need to create the entire apparatus that is a subject in order to accomplish a very specific goal. It's like buying a truck in order to get the wheel. It doesn't scale well. Finally, just like calling `unsubscribe()` yourself, It's also still mixing imperative and functional javascript.

#### The Same Problem at a Bigger Scale

Consider an operator that takes a list of observables and emits values only from the observables earlier in the list than any previous emissions.

Here is this operator done with the event loop.

```
function prefer<T, R>(...observables: Observable<R>[]): Observable<R>{
  return new Observable(observer => {

    const subscrptions = new Array<Subscription>();
    const unsub = (index) => {
      for(let i = index; i < subscrptions.length; i++){
        subscrptions[i].unsubscribe();
      }
    }

    observables.map(stream => stream.pipe(
      delay(0)
    )).forEach((stream, index) => 
      subscrptions.push(stream.subscribe(payload => {
        observer.next(payload);
        unsub(index + 1);
        subscrptions.length = index + 1;
      }))
    );

    return { unsubscribe: () => unsub(0) }
  })
}
```

and then without the event loop and without `unsubscribe()`.

```
function prefer<T, R>(...observables: Observable<R>[]): Observable<R>{
  return defer(() => {

    const wUnsub = observables.map((stream, index) => ({
      stream: stream.pipe(
        map(payload => ({index, payload}))
      ), 
      unsub: new Subject()
    }));

    const unsub = (index) => {
      for(let i = index; i < wUnsub.length; i++){
        wUnsub[i].unsub.next();
        wUnsub[i].unsub.complete();
      }
    }
    
    return merge(...wUnsub.map(build => build.stream.pipe(
      takeUntil(build.unsub)
    ))).pipe(
      tap(({index}) => {
        unsub(index + 1);
        wUnsub.length = index + 1;
      }),
      map(({payload}) => payload),
      finalize(() => unsub(0))
    );
  });
}
```

Also here's the operator in use

```
prefer(
  interval(10000).pipe(
    take(5),
    map(_ => "Every 10s")
  ),
  interval(5000).pipe(map(_ => "Every 5s")),
  interval(1000).pipe(map(_ => "Every 1s")),
  interval(250).pipe(map(_ => "Every 1/4s"))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

Imagine using this operator at scale. It's relatively easy to understand that the memory footprint of the first approach is much smaller than the second approach (O(n) vs O(n*n) memory usage).

---

#### Finally; The Question

Since (in javascript) synchronous code runs to completion before any other code runs, it doesn't seem to make sense to be able to access an observable's `subscription` before the synchronous section of that subscription has returned. Yet, as a means to abort a stream early, it seems that being able to access a stream's `subscription` early might have benefits (at the very least in memory).

Is there a (relatively) elegant way to instrument an Observable to work around these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here's me answering my own question. After working on this for far too long, I stumbled across the fact that it turns out RxJS comes with a pretty good built-in solution. It's only pretty good because it uses `publish/connect` which seems to be implemented with subjects internally (Though the memory footprint is still better? Not sure about why).

This is not really the intended use of `publish/connect`, as I'm not multicasting. The key is that ConnectableObservables do not start with `subscribe`, but rather with `connect`.

You can use this to get at the desired behavior without relying on the event loop at all.

#### Solution Using Publish

Mini-example:

```
const stream = publish()(from([1,2,3,4,5]));

const sub = stream.subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) sub.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});

stream.connect();
```

Scaled to the custom operator:

```
function prefer<T, R>(...observables: Observable<R>[]): Observable<R>{
  return new Observable(observer => {

    const subscrptions = new Array<Subscription>();
    const unsub = (index = 0) => {
      for(let i = index; i < subscrptions.length; i++){
        subscrptions[i].unsubscribe();
      }
    }

    observables
      .map(stream => publish()(stream))
      .map((stream, index) => {
        subscrptions.push(stream.subscribe((payload: R) => {
          observer.next(payload);
          unsub(index + 1);
          subscrptions.length = index + 1;
        }));
        return stream;
      })
      .forEach(stream => stream.connect());

    return { unsubscribe: () => unsub() }
  })
}
```

#### The Difference:

Using the event loop as follows:

```
const stream = from([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  delay(0)
);

console.log("before subscribe");
const sub = stream.subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) sub.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});
console.log("after subscribe");
```

The output: `"before subscribe" "after subscribe" 1 2 3 4`

As apposed to using connect as follows:

```
const stream = publish()(from([1,2,3,4,5]));

const sub = stream.subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) sub.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});

console.log("before connect");
stream.connect();
console.log("after connect");
```

The output: `"before connect" 1 2 3 4 "after connect"`

Because connect keeps synchronous observables, `unsubscribe` can still happen synchronously and the entire observables stream is processed before the line after `connect` is run. That's a pretty big win.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question.

Here would be another approach that **only** works for **RxJS 6.x**:

```js
const sub = from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).subscribe(function(x) {
  if (x > 3) this.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});
/*
1
2
3
4
*/
```

This works because the `subscribe`'s callback will be the assigned to the [`_next` property of `SafeSubscriber`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L183), which is that will be created when you use `.subscribe`.

```js
let context: any = this;

...

next = (<((value: T) => void)> observerOrNext);

...


this._context = context;
this._next = next;
...
```

Then, when the `Subscriber`'s `next` method will be called, under the hood it will happen [something like `next.call(this.context)`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L281), where `this.context` refers to the current `SafeSubscriber` instance. When [`SafeSubscriber.unsubscribe()`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.x/src/internal/Subscriber.ts#L296) is called, it will eventually cause the entire subscriber chain to unsubscribe.

However, this has a **different implementation** in **RxJS 7**, as a result this approach will no longer work.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Never considered the context given to the callbacks as I'm in the habit of using lambda notation.

Comment: @MrkSef yeah, I'm always in favor of anonymous functions, but sometimes a change is required :D

Answer (score 0):

I understood, that you want to unsubscribe to an observable, when your value is greater 3.

```
const sub = from([1,2,3,4,5]).subscribe(x => {
  if(x > 3) sub.unsubscribe();
  console.log(x);
});
```

Do you really need the subscription?
I would rather use the `takeWhile` rxjs operator.

```
from([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(
  takeWhile(x <= 3),
).subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: `take`/`takeWhile` works well when things are simple like in the first example, but would that help me implement the `prefer` operator above? I don't see how. Once you're managing a fleet of streams and unsubscribing is based on their merged values, then it seems to me that `take`/`takeWhile` are no longer expressive enough.